# What symbol is on the staff of The Sorceress by Georges Merle?

Tags: iconography

[image: TheSorceress-GeorgesMerle]

This painting depicts a number of symbols from various cultures. It was shown at a Paris exhibition in 1883, and I suspect the painting is more imagination than an accurate depiction of any  sorceress. That said, the subject holds a staff with a symbol on top. The closest I have found is a "Pagan symbol of Summer" shown on [this site,](https://www.ancient-symbols.com/pagan_symbols.html) which grouped it among other symbols that appear to be western European.

[image] [image]

Is that the symbol used in the painting? If so, why did the artist use a Pagan symbol, if he wanted to affect a non-European vibe?

Comment: Sumer is a region in Asia Minor, now Iraq, and where Babylon was in ancient times. Why did you think "pagan" meant "European"? We could address that point if you clarify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In modern Wicca, this staff is called "The Stang". In its simplest form, a forked staff, Witches use the Stang in various ways including representing the Horned One, aiding in spirit flight, and directing energy.

[image]

Comment: Fascinating! Reading further, the modern Wiccan Stang [might have been influenced by](https://www.patheos.com/blogs/byathameandstang/2016/08/the-stang/) Idries Shah, who wrote about Middle Eastern witch-cults.

Comment: Note that with Horned One the Wicca's do not mean Lucifer/Satan but Cernunnos, an ancient Celtic god with a pair of antlers.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is the symbol of Isis. Here is a picture:
https://www.nationalgeographic.com/content/dam/archaeologyandhistory/rights-exempt/history-magazine/2020/03-04/isis-goddess/isis-mural-temple-horemheb.ngsversion.1584648217707.adapt.1900.1.jpg

Comment: Hello and welcome to mythology and folklore!
Is it possible to elaborate a little more on your answer? And is it possible the picture can be shown here if copyright allows?